# Pasar del jeringozo a palabras

Tags: python-3.7

Hola buenas estaba haciendo un algoritmo donde tengo que pasar una determinada cantidad de frases en jeringoso al idioma español pero nose como eliminar la `p` mas la vocal que se le agrega.

```
#Niveles de refinamiento:

#Primer nivel de refinamiento:
#Se ingresan por medio del usuario la cantidad de lineas en jeringozo que van a ser decodificadas a un idioma.
#Se ingresan cuales son esas lineas a traducir.
#Obtenemos como salida las lineas ya convertidas a dicho idioma.

#Segundo nivel de refinamiento:
#La cantidad de lineas se almacenara como un tipo de dato int.
#Las frases a traducir se almacenan como un tipo de dato string en minuscula y sin espacios.
#Se debera quitar la letra p perteneciente al jeringozo siguiente a una vocal junto con la misma que se repite.
#Por ultimo se procede a mostrar las frases al idioma que corresponde.
```

```py
def convertir(Vector):
    resultado = ""
    p = str
    Vocales = ["aeiou"]
    for letra in Vocales:
        for i in (len(Vector)):
            if Vector[i] == Vocales[p+x]:
                resultado+= Vector[i] - "p" -Vocales[x]
    return resultado   
          
Cantidadsentencia = int(input())

for x in range (0,Cantidadsentencia):
    Lineas = str(input()) 
    Vector.append(Lineas)
        
Lineas = Lineas.lower()
convertir(Vector)
```

Salida

```
Imprime la sentencia decodificada en una sola línea.
Ejemplos de entrada:
2
zepelepenapa papapripikapa
bapas jepe doposapadgapa opovapa kepemipijapa
Ejemplos de salida:
zelena paprika
bas je dosadga ova kemija
```

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: Son los puse para tener como guia

Comment: Nose mas de todo como sacar la p y mas la vocal que se le agrega

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent el `#` indica que se trata de un comentario -_-

Comment: @ValentinoPugliese podrías poner un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y salida?

Comment: @Christian no estaba asi ... aparecía como un titulo ... mira las ediciones...

Comment: Ahi las agregue

Answer (score 1):

Para dar con una solución hay que definir antes claramente qué es el "jerigonzo".

Consiste en añadir sílabas a una frase, por el método siguiente: tan pronto como se encuentra una vocal o grupo de vocales en una sílaba, se añade "p" seguido por esa vocal (o la última de ellas si eran varias), y luego se continúa con el resto de letras de la sílaba. Por ejemplo:

- "La" se convierte en "lapa"
- "Las" se convierte en "lapas"
- "Fra" se convierte en "frapa"
- "Fran" se convierte en "frapan"
- "Bien" se convierte en "biepen"
- etc.

### Pseudocódigo para "deshacer" la jerigonza

```
Preparar dos variables:
  Una para contener la vocal_anteriormente_detectada (inicialmente vacía)
  Otra para indicar si se ha detectado una "p" a eliminar (inicialmente false)

Para cada una de las letras de la frase:

  Si es una "p" y había vocal_anteriormente_detectada
     Marcamos que se ha detectado una "p"
     y saltamos a la siguiente iteración (sin copiar esa p al resultado)

  Si es igual a la vocal_anteriomente_detectada y se había detectado una "p"
     Ponemos de nuevo a false el detector de "p" y la vocal_anteriormente_detectada
     y saltamos a la siguiente iteración (sin copiar esta vocal al resultado)

  Si es una vocal, la guardamos en vocal_anteriormente_detectada

  Copiamos la letra al resultado
```

Si ejecutas "paso a paso" en tu cabeza este algoritmo para la palabra "frapasepe" verás que se van copiando las letras "f", "r", "a" (esta se almacena también en `vocal_anteriormente_detectada`), se salta sin copiar la "p" (porque había una `vocal_anteriormente_detectada`), se salta sin copiar la "a" (porque se había detectado p antes) y se "reinician" las variables centinela. Se sigue con la "s", que es copiada, así como la "e" (además se anota esta como la anteriormente detectada) y después no se copiarán ni "p" ni "e". El resultado sería "frase".

Te dejo como ejercicio el convertir el pseudocódigo a Python :-) (no quiero darte la solución completa porque esto parece un ejercicio de clase, y la mejor forma de aprender es hacerlo uno mismo). Si lo consigues puedes publicarlo como tu propia auto-respuesta. Si te atascas puedes ampliar la pregunta poniendo lo que has intentado y dónde te has atascado.